# Why boost::asio::udp::socket::async_send_to fail with `Operation not permitted` and how should i handle it

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I use boost::asio to send udp package on android platform like this:

```
void SendMessage(Message message, const ip::udp::endpoint& endpoint) {
    bool write_in_progress = !send_queue_.empty();
    send_queue_.emplace(std::make_pair(std::move(message), endpoint));

    if (!write_in_progress) {
        DoSendMessage();
    }
}

void DoSendMessage() {
    service_info_publisher_.async_send_to(
            boost::asio::buffer(send_queue_.front().first),
            send_queue_.front().second,
            std::bind(&ServicePublisher::OnMessageSent,
                      this,
                      std::placeholders::_1));
}

void OnMessageSent(const boost::system::error_code& error) {
    auto& message = send_queue_.front();
    LOGI(kTag,
         "OnMessageSent: content: [{}], dest: [{}:{}]",
         fmt::StringRef((char*) message.first.data(), message.first.size()),
         message.second.address().to_string(),
         message.second.port());

    if (error) {
        LOGE(kTag, "fail to send message, error: [{}]", error.message());
        return;
    }

    send_queue_.pop();
    if (!send_queue_.empty()) {
        DoSendMessage();
    }
}
```

`boost::asio::udp::socket::async_send_to` will fail after some success message sent. The error message was: `Operation not permitted`.

1. When will `boost::asio::udp::socket::async_send_to` fail with `Operation not permitted` and
2. What should i do after `async_send_to` failed, i can not just ignore this error, the io loop seems to be stopped after this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Could be

   - a firewall rejecting your packets. Try disabling it (e.g. conntrack/iptables).
   - lack of pacing (too much UDP traffic at a given destination). See http://www.archivum.info/comp.protocols.tcp-ip/2009-05/00128/Re-UDP-socket-amp-amp-sendto-amp-amp-EPERM.html
2. Yes, your function returns without posting any more async work when you encounter an error. If that's not what you want, simply remove the `return` statement.

   I donot suggest you retry the same because

   - it may just keep failing
   - even unfailed messages might never be received (UDP)

Comment: Added a note about UDP pacing